# What is this blank legend icon in MS Excel column chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, wps-spreadsheet

I don't seem to understand what is this blank series and/or the blue box in legends which has no text next to it. Could someone please help?

Here's the image showing my problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDpcP.png

Comment: Possibly caused by the names being merged across 2 columns. Try putting the names into a single column (A), and the series data into column B onwards.

Comment: You should you provide the Chart range in Table.

Comment: @spikey_richie It worked! Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by your legend data series coming from a merged cell. The name is being used as a legend label from column A, but as you've merged A and B, B is being used as a blank series and applied to the legend.

Simply remove the merge cells on columns A and B, and change the series to look at column A for the labels and legend.